# Spacing between divs

Tags: css, margin, padding, spacing

```
<div id="content">

   <div id="rectangle">

   <p>Consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas at nulla velit, quis bibendum ligula. Donec neque purus, porttitor et tempor non, molestie nec sem.</p>

   </div>
</div>


#content{

    margin:0px auto; 
    height:600px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: white;`enter code here`
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 15px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.07); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 15px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.07); 
    box-shadow: inset 0 15px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.07);   
}



.rectangle {
    width: 563px;
    height: 165px;
    background-color: #e7ebf1; 
    -moz-box-shadow:
        1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2) ,
        inset 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,.6)
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2) ,
        inset 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,.6) ;
    box-shadow:
        1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
        inset 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,.6) 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,.05) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.05) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,.05) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.05) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,.05) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.05) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,.05) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.05) 100%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

I try to create spacing between boxes on top of each other .
Somehow the both stick on top to each other and i cant manage to have spacing between them. 
When i add margin or padding it doesnt change anything .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added class `rectangle` in your CSS but defined id `rectangle` in your HTML.

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/an3QY/3/)

----------- updated give margin-top ------------------ ***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/an3QY/6/)***

Answer (score 0):

The `margin: 0 auto;` is setting the top and bottom margins of the rectangle to 0, so that's why there is no spacing between them.

Set it to `margin: 15px auto;` and you will have space.